# Collections to list in tcl

Tags: list, collections, tcl

Hi I would like to know how to convert a **collection** into **list** in tcl. The output I am getting is in form of collections but I want to change it to list.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "collection" in Tcl context. Please elaborate.

Comment: Perhaps, you can show what your input (collection) looks like, and what you want the output (list) looks like.

Comment: Maybe he means a dictionary or a (TclX) keyed list?

Comment: I think he means an array, but unless he tells us, we can't answer the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally we use collections when dumping/querying data from certain tools which use TCL (for example Design compiler from synopsys). These collections look as list but are not accessible for normal list commands. To access them you need to use "foreach_in_collection" command and need to use get_object_name (or equivalent command) and need to build list (lappend) of the output of get_object_name. From this list you can use all TCL list operations.

foreach_in_collection and get_object_name  are tool specific commands and can not be found in TCL and they work only run through tool interface.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are using some synopsys tool:

```
  set MyList [get_object_name $MyCollection]
```

The above should convert your collection to a list.

Answer (score 6):

The user is likely talking about Synopsys Tcl "collections" -- an extension provided by EDA vendors like Synopsys to support a list of objects in their Tcl API.

I'm late to the party, but this simple proc is what you'll want most of the time.  Note that since you'll be mapping your collection to a list of object "names" you are losing information with this mapping:

```
proc col2list { col } {
   set list ""
   foreach_in_collection c $col { lappend list [get_object_name $c] }
   return $list
}
```